# import SQL tables from database into Pandas Dataframe without knowing the whole name of the tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I have something probably easy to do but I didn't find the exact answer for now. I would like to import multiple tables from a database into Spyder using python and sqlite. I have a list target_unique that contains specific targets like lung, tum, etc but I am not supposed to know all targets that's why I just would like to write something easy like variable+string name like target+'_ref_seg_table' but I have no idea if it's possible inside an SQL query. My list target_unique is in Spyder and not in the database. This is what I've tried basically among other codes that didn't work.

```
if largest: # If the latest version of InventoryDB exist (DB with the highest number)
    #print("largest exist")
    #version+=1
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect(largest) # we connect to this latest version of InventoryDB
    cur2 = conn2.cursor()
    for target in target_unique:
        vars()[target+'_ref_seg_table_previous'] = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM"+ target+"_ref_seg_table", conn2)
```

Maybe I should transfer the list target unique in the database to be able to use target+'ref_seg_table' ?
And I think I don't need the vars() here, I just used it before to create the current tables target+'ref_seg_table', but for the previous tables I think I won't need it.
I've also tried using regex for selecting the correct tables but still not working neither...

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to do it if it can help other people I post it here :

```
if largest: # If the latest version of InventoryDB exist (DB with the highest number)
    #print("largest exist")
    #version+=1
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect(largest) # we connect to this latest version of InventoryDB
    cur2 = conn2.cursor()
    # sql query to count how much tables named Series_table there are in the latest version of InventoryDB
    cur2.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Series_table' ''') 
    
    for target in target_unique: # For each target in model table
    # We import manual cols from ref seg tables from the latest InventoryDB available and we store them as target_ref_seg_table_previous
        vars()[target+'_ref_seg_table_previous'] = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT mycolumns FROM {}_ref_seg_table".format(target),conn2)
```

I just used .format !